# How do you prove this using mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I am unsure if my proof method is correct for this problem here:

Use mathematical induction to prove that for each integer $n ≥ 3, 4^n ≤ 5^n − 60.$

This is my working out so far:

Base case
$n = 3,$  $4^3 ≤ 5^3 - 60$. P(3) is true

Inductive hypothesis: Assume P(k) is true.
Show $P(k+1)$ is true.

$4^{k+1} ≤ 5^{k+1} - 60$.

LHS = $4^{k+1}$

= $4(4^k)$

$<4(5^k)-60$

$<5(5^k)-60$

= $5^{k+1}-60$

Therefore, by the principle of mathematical induction?, for every integer $n ≥ 3, 4^n ≤ 5^n − 60.$

Not quite sure if this is the right way to prove it.

Comment: Note that the right hand side becomes $4 \times 5^k - 240 < 5^{k+1} - 60$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

$4(4^k)$

$<4(5^k)-60$

It should be $$4(4^k) <4(5^k-60) = 4\cdot 5^k-240 <5\cdot 5^k-240 <5^{k+1}-60$$